# How to use a recursive method with arguments in context of array_map(...)?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, array-map

I have an array and want to iterate it and apply a class method to every element. For this purpose one can use `array_map(...)` or `array_walk(...)`. If it's a multidimensional array, `array_walk_recursive(...)` can be used.

What I have now is following case:

```
Array (
    [form_fieldset_aaa] => Array (
        [form_element_bbb] => Array (
            [validation_error_type_foo] => error message...
        )
        [form_fieldset_ccc] => Array (
            [form_fieldset_ddd] => Array (
                [form_fieldset_eee] => Array (
                    [form_element_fff] => Array (
                        [validation_error_type_bar] => error message...
                    )
                )
            )
            [form_fieldset_ggg] => Array (
                [1] => Array (
                    [form_fieldset_hhh] => Array (
                        [validation_error_type_buz] => error message...
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

1. a multidimensional (associative) array;
2. a method, that needs to be applied to every element (recursively);
3. the method needs to get not only the current `key` and `value`, but also the additional information like the `key` and `value` of the parent element and an object for `$newObject = $object->get($parentKey)`.

**How to implement that requirement?**

Comment: I'm unclear on the third requirement. Does it boil down to creating a method that accepts parameters like this: `$someObject->someMethod($key, $value, $parentKey, $parentValue, $newObject);`?

Comment: @HPierce Yes, exactly. The method also need one further argument, but it's a "static" one, that means, it's something, that in a closure would be passed over `use`. `$someObject->someMethod($key, $value, $parentKey, $parentValue, $newObject, $oneFurtherArgument);`